# Как в переменную поместить переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Очень хочу сделать произвольные текста в одной функции. Но столкнулся с вопросом - как поместить переменную в переменную с текстом?

Допустим у нас есть переменная N, значение которой - 311

После этого, мы допустим пишем следующий текст:

```
В стране лилипутов очень жарко

Но человечков там... аж {N}

Остерегайтесь людей на лодках!
```

И данный текст также уходит в переменную X

И необходимо, чтобы в переменной X с текстом, где-то по-середине как показано выше, появилось это значение из N?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f-строки, например:

```py
N = 311

print(f"""
В стране лилипутов очень жарко

Но человечков там... аж {N}

Остерегайтесь людей на лодках!""")
```

Вывод:

```
В стране лилипутов очень жарко

Но человечков там... аж 311

Остерегайтесь людей на лодках!
```

Comment: Вы немножко не поняли - текст тоже переменная. Но спасибо за ответ, успел разобраться сам. Думал питон не даст мне сделать строку следующего формата:

print(text.format())

Comment: @ArthurLangley-Reddle `успел разобраться сам` Тогда может опубликуете ваше решение? `Думал питон не даст мне сделать строку следующего формата:` А вот тут я не понял, о чём вы.

Comment: @mironovmeow -  прошу

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему достаточно просто.. аж стыдно что сразу не догадался

Входные данные (текст):

```
В стране лилипутов очень жарко

Но человечков там... аж {count}

Остерегайтесь людей на лодках!
```

Входные данные (кол-во) - 311

Вывод:

```py
print(text.format(count = N))
```

Comment: А, так вот что вы хотели. Тогда добавлю немного статей про форматирование на питоне: [habr](https://habr.com/ru/company/wunderfund/blog/674866/ "F-строки в Python мощнее, чем можно подумать"), [pythonworld](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html "Самоучитель: Форматирование строк. Метод format")